# How can capture like event of facebook like button on iframe?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have developed the following ling:
http://www.mandanemedia.com/freelancer/

```
<iframe id="targetFrame" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages/MandaneMediacom/275554465891715&width=300&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&border_color=%23ffffff&stream=false&header=false&height=258" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:258px;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

It is a iframe which after 2 sec show people the facebook like button. Now the issue is that the client wants when a user press like button, this iframe be closed.

how can i capture the fire event like in this situation.
I can capture it by facebook event or i can capture it by javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can't track an event if you are using the iframe version of the social plugin. You need to use either the HTML5 or FBML (HTML5 is recommended)

You have to include this after your body tag:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId:'YOURAPPID',channelUrl : '//YOURDOMAIN/channel.html',status:true,cookie: true, xfbml: true });
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
          function(response) {
            $('#floating-box').hide();
        }
    );
  };


  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

And your div should be something like this:

```
    <div id="floating-box">
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/MandaneMediacom/275554465891715" data-width="300" data-height="258" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
</div>
```

**SOURCE:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Thanks for you help, i have change it from iframe, just the  edge.create is not working, would you please guide me? http://www.mandanemedia.com/freelancer/demo3/